# Determine if ASP.NET application is running locally

Tags: .net, asp.net, localhost

I want to know if there is a recommended way of determining if an asp application is running locally. At the moment I use the Request object and do a string search for localhost or 127.0.0.1 on the server variable but this has several limitations. The biggest one being that the Request object is not always available when I need it.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

See [HttpRequest.IsLocal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal.aspx)

```
bool isLocal = HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal;
```

Comment: What about where Request is null. i.e: Application_start?

Comment: @mmtemporary during the Application_Start there is no request, there is no reason to check if the Request.IsLocal or not. If you want to use it on Global.asax, consider using it inside Application_BeginRequest.

Comment: @ViniciusRocha In some scenario we want check that when Request is null.

Comment: We have UnityContainer for resolving dependency injection. We have an IEnvironment dependency telling us if it's local, staging or production. We need to resolve this when request is null.

Comment: @NickNiebling Seems a confusion of terms... I think this question is about determining if the current request is coming from the machine that executes the web application - which of course only makes sense if there IS a current request. It sounds like you Perhaps really mean if it's running on production, staging or a _developer_ machine? As for how to determine that, I think only you can decide how to differentiate between them. Configuration file? Machine name pattern? Name of system account that executes the ASP.Net engine?

Comment: @OskarBerggren you are certainly right. I must have misunderstood "Local" (and confused it with localhost). ASP.NET Core 1 now has [IHostingEnvironment](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html?highlight=IHostingEnvironment), but for other websites/services we still have to detect it like you suggest :-) But we kind of adopted the IHostingEnvironment approach and implemented our own similar "IEnvironment" elsewhere.

Comment: I don't agree @mmtemporary with the logic here. Application_BeginRequest is fine if you're dealing with a request, at which point Request.IsLocal is fine. However the statement that there's no reason to check it in Application_Start is valid. As an example we bootstrap Hangfire in this to setup some background jobs. This can't be done in BeginRequest because it needs to be ready before that, so the obvious place is Application_Start. No way to tell using IsLocal there since there's no request.

Comment: @MehMan I've though on a solution for this and posted it as an aswer on this thread, in case you'd like to take a look.

Answer (score 14):

You can check the Request.IsLocal property

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me with Application_Start

```
if (!HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopmentEnvironment)
{
      GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
}
```

To know more about how IsDevelopmentEnvironment is set, please look at the following thread.

[In ASP.NET, what determines the value of HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopmentEnvironment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135304/in-asp-net-what-determines-the-value-of-hostingenvironment-isdevelopmentenviron)

Comment: There is also the opposite if anyone is locking for that: HostingEnvironment.IsHosted

Answer (score 5):

In response to @Meh Men's comment for other answer in this thread, who asked:

> What about where Request is null. i.e: Application_start?

If you are sure your production and test or "homolog" versions of your website will all be deployed with a release version of your website, while your local environment will be built and developed in "debug" mode, you can make use of `#if DEBUG` sintax to write code which only should be run locally, while outside of this block, or even inside a matching `#else` block, you may write some other code which you want to be run only when not locally (e.g: remotely).

Here is a small sample of how I've solved this problem in a particular project I'm curreltly working on:

```
#if DEBUG
    // Code here will only be run locally.
#else
    // Code here will only be run "remotely".
```

Comment: This is gold! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In a MVC view / ASP page / code behind class:

```
bool isLocal = HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal;
```

In an MVC controller :

```
bool isLocal = Request.IsLocal;
```

Answer (score 1):

Request.IsLocal is the same as checking for 127.0.0.1 or ::1. See this post: http://forums.asp.net/p/1065813/4081335.aspx.

Comment: Yes, but using a standard library call conveys the intention of the code better, IMO. I would prefer to use the library rather than write my own code to do such a simple thing.

Comment: I agree. I just wanted to point out that since the designated answer may be the same code as what the poster was using, the answer may have the same limitations.

Comment: That link is not correct.  If I hit my server locally via its IP Address, HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal correctly returns true, but the UserHostAddress is the real IP address, not 127.0.0.1 (or ::1).  Tested in .NET 4.

Comment: as mhenry1384 points out.. `IsLocal` also refers to when you visiting the IIS site from the SAME machine. Doing so also displays YSOD detailed error messages by default too, when coming in from local machine.

Answer (score 1):

If HttpContext.Current is not null use

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal
```

Otherwise, for example in the App_Start or before HttpContext.Current is available, you can test

```
HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath.StartsWith(@"C:\")
```

or a dedicated disk on your PC.

Another way can be use a constant compilation variable set in production, for example from Azure and visualstudio.com if you use them.

It is dirty, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I approached this by creating an entry in `.gitignore` for a secret json file,  `appsettings.secrets.json`:

```
{
  "Environment": "localhost"
}
```

Then in `Program.cs`, utilize this to check if it is local or not:

```
builder
    .Configuration.
    .AddJsonFile(
        "appsettings.secret.json", 
        optional: true,
        reloadOnChange: true
    );

...

bool isLocalDev = builder.Configuration["Environment"] == "localhost";

if (isLocalDev)
{
    // Local configuration
}
```

Doing it this way will disallow any remote runner from enabling a local version and no deployment changes are required.

Answer (score 0):

Request is not always available in ASP.NET environment?

HttpContext and its properties Request/Response are initialized as soon as the server starts processing the page. So at any place you can execute c# code in your page life cycle you should be able to check the request url.

Comment: I didn't realise that I could use the HttpContext class to access the Request object.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what other method of accessing the Request object is available? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, Request and HttpContext objects are not always available in ASP.NET application. For example `Application_Start` is executed with no HTTPContext.

Comment: @negative, but Application_Start is not executed on every request and certainly not during page life cycle.

Comment: @RomanR. jobs created in `Application_Start` may be always running on the background. Also the question has nothing to do with page requests.

Comment: I have found that HttpContext.Current is null in some cases such as local RDLC reports - I had null exception problems with object properties used in reports that tried to access HttpContext.Current. I had to re-work these properties so as not to rely on HttpContext.Current.

Comment: ^ So then what do you rely on?

Comment: Another example is when Castle Windsor is loading services. HttpContext.Current.Request will throw with an error saying that it isn't available in that context. You can't even check it for null without it throwing.