# How to tell if code is running locally from Visual Studio/Cassini

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, iis, compiler-directives

I have an interface, let's call it `ILocateLogFile`, with a standard implementation for dev/beta/production servers, and one that only works in the local development environment.  I can't seem to think of a nice clean way to decide (preferably at compile time, but runtime would be fine) if I'm running locally or on a server.  This is a WCF application hosted on IIS, if that matters.

The best I've come up with is to use a compiler symbol, something like:

```
    ILocateLogFile locateLogFile;
#if DEBUG
    locateLogFile = new DevSandboxLogFileLocator();
#else
    locateLogFile = new LogFileLocator();
#endif
```

The problem is, compile symbols get set by the build, which I don't control, and I want to be certain.  Isn't there some automagical way to check for the presence of Visual Studio?  Or at least to check for Cassini rather than IIS?

Comment: I've seen this solved before by checking for the server name variable in an if else statement.

Comment: Any reason not to use .config files to configure logging? (likely you already have different .config for each environment, so may be trivial to add logging too).

Comment: @RandomUs1r that's a good suggestion, but I can't use `System.Web.HttpContext` because my WCF service isn't using ASP.Net compatibility...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I do have a reason, though maybe not a cogent one -- we're running locally from the same .config as on the Dev server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two ways I have done this 1 you can check the process name

```
bool isRunningInIisExpress = Process.GetCurrentProcess()
                                .ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("iisexpress");
```

Or update your config file with a custom setting

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ApplicationEnvironment" value="LOCAL_DEV" />
</appSettings>
```

That you update specifically for each environment and have you application query for

I'm  not sure if there is a way to determine this at compile time, besides having a special build configuration that is for each environment and putting a custom `PRAGMA` for each of these builds. Personally I think that is not as elegant, but it could also work.

Comment: Thanks, I think the first option is exactly what I'm looking for -- although, my process name seems to be "WebDev.WebServer40" rather than "iisexpress".

Comment: That makes sense if you're using the build in development server. You may want to think about switching over to IIS Express. I have found it's way more robust and is build into VS 2012/2010 SP1.

Answer (score 0):

I found this here and it worked for me- 
[Determine if ASP.NET application is running locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691881/determine-if-asp-net-application-is-running-locally/691886)

```
bool isLocal = HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal;
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is the code I used

```
If Debugger.IsAttached Then
 ' Since there is a debugger attached,
 ' assume we are running from the IDE
Else
 ' Assume we aren't running from the IDE
End If
```