# In ASP.NET, what determines the value of HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopmentEnvironment?

Tags: asp.net

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.isdevelopmentenvironment.aspx) does not explain how, when or why this value is set to true.

Setting `<configuration debug="false" />` in web.config does not set the property to false, nor does setting `<deployment retail="true" />` in machine.config.

I'm running the test website from Visual Studio 2012 on IIS Express, I do not have IIS 'proper' installed.

Edit:
After reviewing Oscar's answer and doing some more research, it seems that setting `<deployment retail="true" />` should override, so I probably didn't set it in the right framework's machine.config when I asked this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The decompiled code of this property is as follows:

```
public static bool IsDevelopmentEnvironment
{
    get
    {
        return ((AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData(".devEnvironment") as bool?) == true);
    }
}
```

But I couldn't fin where this value is set.. :-(

Comment: Curious, I found this [disassembly of System.Web](http://dotnetinside.com/framework/v4.0.30319/System.Web/ApplicationManager), there is a method  `ApplicationManager.EnvironmentInfo.GetWasLaunchedFromDevelopmentEnvironment()`. It looks at the "DEV_ENVIRONMENT" environment variable, if it's set to 1, then the setting is true.

Comment: Here's an [updated link](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/Hosting/ApplicationManager.cs,80e692b47a846e09) to the ApplicationManager code.